# Use advanced custom fields value in js for google maps marker

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I want to use advanced custom fields to place a Google Map icon. I prefer using the repeater field, but first i'am trying to accomplish a regular field. Image field output is url. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong?

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
<script>
<?php $image = get_field('marker'); ?>

function initialize() {

        //add map, the type of map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.355692, 5.619524),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        //add locations
        var locations = [
            ['Hotspot1', 52.355889, 5.619535,'<?php echo $image ;?>'],
            ['Hotspot2', 52.354349, 5.618924,'$get_google_map']
        ];

        //declare marker call it 'i'
        var marker, i;

        //declare infowindow
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        //add marker to each locations
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3]
            });

            //click function to marker, pops up infowindow
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>                
            <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=hidden&callback=initialize">
            </script>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Gino

Comment: To help us debug, does $image have a value? Try to echo it somewhere you can see the output, or use php to get type. echo gettype($image)

Comment: It it working now, but i cant get the repeater working.

Answer (score 0):

Missing an echo for `$get_google_map`. Not sure what that represents either since it's not defined

```
  var locations = [
        ['Hotspot1', 52.355889, 5.619535,'<?php echo $image ;?>'],
        ['Hotspot2', 52.354349, 5.618924,'$get_google_map']
    ];
```

Should be

```
  var locations = [
        ['Hotspot1', 52.355889, 5.619535,'<?php echo $image ;?>'],
        ['Hotspot2', 52.354349, 5.618924,'<?php echo $get_google_map ;?>']
    ];
```

Inspect the output in browser source to see what the `locations` array actually looks like or log it to your console with `console.log(locations)`

Comment: It works now with a single field, but i cant get the repeater field working.. and i cant place another answer

Comment: what is `repeater field`? No idea what that means

Comment: Repeater is a custom field from acf; read more here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

See my code here: http://puu.sh/rcoH4/e18a63e3c0.png

Comment: your `while` loop overwrites the variables in each iteration ... need them to be in an array then use `echo json_encode($array)` to output array to javascript variable

Comment: Hmm this goes above my coding knowledge i guess. Where do i need to start?

Comment: can you give a little headsup?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply. I changed the code into this:

```
            <script>
            <?php $image = get_field('marker'); ?>


            function initialize() {
                //add map, the type of map
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 15
                    , center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.355692, 5.619524)
                    , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                //add locations
                var locations = [
        ['Hotspot1', 52.355889, 5.619535, '<?php echo $image ;?>']
        , ['Hotspot2', 52.354349, 5.618924, '<?php echo $image ;?>']
    ];
```

Because *$get_google_map* was from previous testing. But unfortunately the 
*$image* doesn't output anything.

Comment: The **$image = get_field('marker');** is not outside The Loop? If it is, then it is advised to put the post ID after the 'marker'.